# Difference between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many in layman's terms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to understand how rails association work. I was able to comprehend the all the associations except the 2 mentioned above.

Where and Why exactly has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many associations are used ?

Please provide the simplest answer possible with scenarios

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

[Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

[ActiveRecord Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).
>
> **You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model.**

Answer (score 1):

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is a relic from Rails 1. There's no reason to use it. It follows a separate, less supported, and more problematic codepath than `has_many :through` [which they're getting rid of in master](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md):

> has_and_belongs_to_many is now transparently implemented in terms of has_many :through. Behavior should remain the same, if not, it is a bug.

Anything you can do with `has_and_belongs_to_many` you can do with `has_many :through` If I were to post code samples, I'd only be explaining the limitations of `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: Also, unrelated to the question but on the topic of things to avoid, don't use `default_scope`.

Answer (score 0):

Both are used for the same purpose i.e. for creating the many_to_many relationship in rails. Just they have the different syntax. Suppose there are two table Product and Category and if we want to create many_to_many relationship between these two tables, then we should do something like this:

**has_and_belongs_to_many**

in migration

```
def self.up  
  create_table 'categories_products', :id => false do |t|    
    t.column :category_id, :integer    
    t.column :product_id, :integer    
  end    
end
```

models/product.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

models/category.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

**has_many :through**

models/categorization.rb

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :category
```

models/product.rb

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
```

models/category.rb

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :products, :through => :categorizations
```

Now developers used has_many :through for creating many_to_many relationship as it is less complicated and easy to use